# re.findall() returning the wrong values when using optionals

Tags: python, regex

I'm following along in a tutorial and I seem to be stuck on what seems to be an easy thing to do:

```
numRegex = re.compile(r'\d+(\s+\w+)?')
spam = numRegex.findall("my address is   999 Street Ave City CA 95014 x")
print(len(spam))
print(spam)
```

this returns `[' Street', ' x']` which is obviously wrong as it should be `['999 Street', '95014 x']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are capturing the group wrongly. Try:

```
numRegex = re.compile(r'(\d+(?:\s+\w+)?)')
```

Or,

```
numRegex = re.compile(r'\d+(?:\s+\w+)?')
```

`\d+(\s+\w+)?` seeks for the whole pattern, but only matches `(\s+\w+)` part because, this is the capturing group.

You need to match the whole pattern. So, you should add a parenthesis  over the whole pattern to match the whole pattern as captured group.

Now, You have one nested capturing group `(\s+\w+)?`. You need to make it a non capturing group. So, Add a `?:` inside the parenthesis to get the effect.

Comment: is the last `?` needed? can you explain your changes?

Comment: Ok i definetly would not have guessed that, can you point me to a resource where I can find that and read up on it please? The tutorial im following along did not cover that and I came accross this problem because I was trying to test the functionality

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, That depends on OPs usecases, the part `(\s+\w+)` may or may not exist. I've just used OPs attempt and made it workable.

Comment: ok that works to an extent, however if i try to add the "optional" argument between the regex I get weird returns. For instance, numRegex = re.compile(r'(\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+(:?(\s+\w+)?)\s+\d+)')

Comment: May be you are using it wrong. What are you trying to achieve with this attempted pattern?